# Shopify - Order File CSV to text file

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

Is there a way to convert order csv file to text file? i'm guessing this may need to be converted using API but open to suggestions

or if there are any marketplace apps in shopify that can conver them?

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not, CSV is actually a text file. Always has been, always will be. The things people screw up when working with CSV include this fun list:

- line endings can be windows, mac, or other
- some people use characters other than a comma to separate fields
- some people quote data, others do not
- some people forget headers

But all in all, Shopify CSV is nothing but a text file. So I think your question is answered fine. If on the other hand you meant something else, please do let us know!

Comment: hey David thanks for the clarification. I think i was referring to .csv vs. .txt format. Just wanted to know if it was possible.

Comment: If you rename a CSV to TXT, nothing magical happens. It is a trick though, to rename TXT to CSV, and then you can easily import to a program like Excel, whereas if you import TXT to Excel, it often fails to pick up on the data being comma-delimited. Excel sucks sometimes! Especially when it guesses your 10-digit or greater integer is scientific notation, which it is not.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert an Excel worksheet to a text file by using the Save As command.

- Go to File > Save As.
- Click Browse.

In the Save As dialog box, under Save as type box, choose the text file format for the worksheet; for example, click Text (Tab delimited) or CSV (Comma delimited).

Export data to a text file by saving it

Comment: I want this to be automated when syncing order files from shopify to an erp system which can only take txt file.